# How to replace this light

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

[image]

Just trying to figure out if this is replaceable and diy (and if it is, how I replace it) or if it’s wired in and I need to contact my landlord to fix it

Comment: Difficult to tell from the picture, but it does not appear to be a more modern integrated-LED recessed lighting. If it is a replaceable bulb, the best way to tell is to try unscrewing it.

Comment: If it's LED (sory, pics are not showing for me right now), there's a good chance you'll have to have the landlord replace the whole fixture.

Comment: Probably some kind of halogen.  Either way, it's the landlord's problem.  (Well, it could be yours if the LL doesn't do his job.)

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from the picture, but it seems halogen so it should be easy to replace. There are different mechanisms, try rotating the middle part or the outer ring (carefully) until something starts moving.
This clip shows it well: https://youtu.be/bXIlnoJTLaw

Comment: Looks like a normal MR-16 where you cut the paint and pull down the outer ring (with the light having been off for a while for cooling).